# Expected value of a product with indicator function, using brownian motion

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $\{X(t);t\geq 0\}$ be an IID stochastic process given by:
$dX(t) = \mu X (t) dt + \sigma X(t) dW(t)$ where $W(t)\sim N(0,1)$ and $\mu,\sigma>0$ are constants.

I want to calculate: $E[\max(aX(t)+b,0) \mid X(s) = x]$

So I do the following:

$E[\max(aX(t)+b,0)]=E[(aX+b)I\{aX+b\geq0\}]=aE[XI\{X\geq-\frac{b}{a}\}]+bP(X\geq -\frac{b}{a})$, where $I$ is the indicator function.

Under expectation we have $aE[XI\{X\geq-\frac{b}{a}\}] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xI\{x\geq-\frac{b}{a}\}\phi(x)dx$ where $\phi$ is the pdf of normal distribution. But I don't know how i should handle this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Informations are missing. Who is $X$? Are the $X(t)$ iid ?

Comment: Yes, they are IID, I added in the question now

Comment: If they are i.i.d., then the event $X(s)=x$ is independent of the value of $X(t)$ unless $s=t$.  So you're looking for $\operatorname{E}\left( \max\{aX+b, 0\} \right)$ where $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and the process depending on the variable $t$ is irrelevant.  However, I suspect some confusing in the formulation of the question. $\qquad$

Comment: I fixed a serious error in the question. I have added details now. $X(t)$ is a geometric brownian motion

Comment: Well it is very similar to the way we derive the black scholes equation.. Are you familiar with girsanov theorem to change the measure? Anyhow just look at the proof of the bs equation and you should be able to replicate it